# Expected Value of observable Wigner Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am currently working on a problem to prove the formula for calculating the expected value of an Operator:
$$E(\hat{A})=\int dx dp W(x,p,t)\tilde{A}(x,p)$$
where
$$W(x,p,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar} \int dy \rho(x+y/2, x-y/2,t) e^{-ipy/\hbar}$$
and
$$\tilde{A}(x,p)=\int dy \langle x+y/2 | \hat{A} |x-y/2\rangle e^{-ipy/\hbar}$$
After plugging in the last two definitions it is quite straight forward. First by carrying out the integration with respect to $p$ one gets a Dirac Delta $\delta({z+y\over \hbar})$;  then carrying out the integration with respect to either $z$ or $y$.

One is then left with the following expression:
$$  \int dx dz \langle x+z/2|\hat{\rho}|x-z/2\rangle\langle x-z/2| \hat{A}|x+z/2\rangle$$
Then by doing a simple substitution:
$u=x-z/2$ and $v=x+z/2$ One can arrive at:
$$  \int du dv \langle v|\hat{\rho}|u\rangle\langle u| \hat{A}|v\rangle$$
This where I am not sure how to proceed.
Can one just say that the middle ket bra is just the identity operator such that one arrives at:
$$ \int dv \langle v|\hat{\rho}\hat{A}|v\rangle=Tr(\rho A)=E(\hat{A})$$

Comment: Your resolution of the identity is sound.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks. The question I put is actually quite silly in hindsight.